# How to return user defined table types from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

My requirement is to return a user defined table from a stored procedure based on passing id.

First I create my table type as :

```
CREATE TYPE test AS TABLE 
(
    id int not null,
    name nvarchar(50) not null,
    value nvarchar(50) not null
)
```

Now I defined my stored procedure as :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_test
    @id int,
    @racun_stavke dbo.test READONLY -- I need this as OUTPUT ?
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*FILL MY OUTPUT Type Table AS I LIKE and return*/
       //enter code here

END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a user defined function instead of a stored procedure. It's very straight forward and quite well explained at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485(v=sql.80).aspx

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LargeOrderShippers ( @FreightParm money )
RETURNS @OrderShipperTab TABLE
   (
    ShipperID     int,
    ShipperName   nvarchar(80),
    OrderID       int,
    ShippedDate   datetime,
    Freight       money
   )
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT @OrderShipperTab
        SELECT S.ShipperID, S.CompanyName,
           O.OrderID, O.ShippedDate, O.Freight
        FROM Shippers AS S INNER JOIN Orders AS O
              ON S.ShipperID = O.ShipVia
        WHERE O.Freight > @FreightParm
   RETURN
END
```

Comment: You are right, that a TVF is a good answer here (+1 from my side). **But**: Multi-Statement TVF are something one should avoid if ever possible. They are known for **very bad** performance. Sometimes there is no way around, but in most cases (CTEs are great for this!) it is possbile to create the internal `SELECT` as a one-liner. Inlineable (ad-hoc) TVF are **really great!** and way better than the usual way to use SPs just to read data. Another way'd be a simple VIEW...

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the performance issue, I was not aware of that!